# Do some versions of Yacc use '=' between rules and actions?

Tags: bison, yacc

I am compiling a very old program (wu-ftpd 2.6.1 circa 2000) and it was failing on this code:

```
cmd_list:   /* empty */
    | cmd_list cmd
    =   {
        fromname = (char *) NULL;
        restart_point = 0;
    }
    | cmd_list rcmd
    ;
```

Bison says the problem is the unexpected '=' which makes sense, as every other Yacc program I've seen (admittedly not very many) does not use an '=' sign there. I've replaced the `=\t{` pattern with `\t{` and the software builds (with many warnings of course) but I'm wondering how it was built in the past. Has Yacc syntax changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, very old versions of yacc allowed the semantic action to be signaled with an `=`. They also allowed actions consisting of single statements without enclosing braces.

This syntax was noted as obsolete in [Stephen Johnson's original Yacc paper](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/), which dates from the 1970s. See *Appendix D: Old Features Supported but not Encouraged*:

> 5. Actions may also have the form
>
>    ```
>     =     { . . . }
>    ```
>
>    and the curly braces can be dropped if the action is a single C statement.

I did a quick check on my hard drive and found that the `={...}` syntax was accepted by bison 1.2.5 (1996), but it doesn't seem to be present in v1.875 (2003). Somewhere between those two versions, bison's original hand-built lexer was replaced with a lexer generated by (f)lex (and the hand-built parser was replaced with a bootstrapped parser); I suppose the obsolete syntax never made it into the new parser.

Comment: Funny — I was looking at the paper from that site earlier this afternoon (for a set of reasons unrelated to this question).

Comment: I guess that demonstrates that old resources are always valuable, if only for historical reference. But these days, I don't think I'd use that document for anything unrelated to computer history. I often wish it didn't pop up so often on internet searches, since people really should be using https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html

Comment: Yup. I was amused mostly. It didn’t really correspond to what I was looking for, and I didn’t expect it to when I saw the author.  I was just checking that it was what I thought it was — the original specification for Yacc that I learned Yacc from.